# Flutter: Direct Firebase Craslytics to a specific app in project

Tags: flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I have a Flutter mobile app for Android and iOS. I have a Firebase project that I use for notifications and google login auth. The project has 4 applications on it. 2 for iOS and 2 for Android. The reason I have 2 for each is one of it is for production env and the other one is for my test env.

I set up my Firebase Crashlytics and I am getting reports to my dashboard. My Problem is I can't choose which application in my Firebase console the data reports to. During my configuration, I could choose only which platform but I couldn't choose the specific app for that platform so right now both my test and prod env send the data to the production app firebase dashboard for instance Android-prod.

I have a Firebase options files but it seems to ignore it and default to something i cant find. The Firebase options file WORKS for my notifications.

My code is this:

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    final FirebaseApp app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
      name: 'kompa-386909',
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );

    FlutterError.onError = (errorDetails) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordFlutterFatalError(errorDetails);
    };
    PlatformDispatcher.instance.onError = (error, stack) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance.recordError(error, stack, fatal: true);
      return true;
    };
```

And my firebase options looks like this for example:

```
class DefaultFirebaseOptions {
  static FirebaseOptions android = FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: dotenv.env['FLUTTER_APP_ENV']! == 'test'
        ? '****'
        : '****',
    appId: dotenv.env['FLUTTER_APP_ENV']! == 'test'
        ? '****'
        : '****',
    messagingSenderId: dotenv.env['FLUTTER_APP_ENV']! == 'test'
        ? '****'
        : '****',
    projectId: dotenv.env['FLUTTER_APP_ENV']! == 'test'
        ? 'kompa-386909'
        : 'kompa-386909',
    storageBucket: dotenv.env['FLUTTER_APP_ENV']! == 'test'
        ? '****'
        : '****',
  );
```

With proper info that is hidden here. If I print the results of the final FirebaseApp app I get all the right information.

My question is how can I direct the info so it chooses the proper Android-prod or Android-test app for sending the analytics data or should I use a different approach? The current approach works fine for my notifications.